# Clearing content of text file using php

Tags: php, html, text-files

I have a filelist.txt file and I created a file called clear.php to clear the content of filelist.

I put a button in index.html to call clear.php to clear the file.

Can anyone help me out regarding what PHP code I should write in clear.php?

How to code a button to call clear.php and then return back to index.html showing the result that it has been cleared?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
file_put_contents("filelist.txt", "");
```

You can redirect by using the [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to modify the Location header.

Comment: Keep in mind that as the _function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file_,  doing `file_put_contents("filelist.txt", "") or die("Could not clear file!");` will always die.

Answer (score 42):

This would truncate the file:

```
$fh = fopen( 'filelist.txt', 'w' );
fclose($fh);
```

In clear.php, redirect to the caller page by making use of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` value.

Comment: Your solution helped me, but i implemented Andy E's solution, well your solution is also 100% correct.
Thank you for helping me out!!

Answer (score 18):

```
//create a file handler by opening the file
$myTextFileHandler = @fopen("filelist.txt","r+");

//truncate the file to zero
//or you could have used the write method and written nothing to it
@ftruncate($myTextFileHandler, 0);

//use location header to go back to index.html
header("Location:index.html");
```

I don't exactly know where u want to show the result.

Answer (score 5):

To add **button** you may use either [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/click/) libraries or simple Javascript script as shown below:

**HTML** link or button:

```
<a href="#" onClick="goclear()" id="button">click event</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var btn = document.getElementById('button');
function goclear() { 
alert("Handler called. Page will redirect to clear.php");
document.location.href = "clear.php";
};
</script>
```

Use **PHP** to clear a file content. For instance you can use the **fseek($fp, 0);** or **ftruncate ( resource $file , int $size )** as below:

```
<?php
//open file to write
$fp = fopen("/tmp/file.txt", "r+");
// clear content to 0 bits
ftruncate($fp, 0);
//close file
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Redirect **PHP** - you can use **header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )**

```
<?php
header('Location: getbacktoindex.html');
?>
```

I hope it's help.

Answer (score 4):

Use `'w'` and not, `'a'`.

```
if (!$handle = fopen($file, 'w'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try fopen()
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

w as mode will truncate the file.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $fp = fopen("$address",'w+');
 if(!$fp)
    echo 'not Open';
        //-----------------------------------
 while(!feof($fp))
     {
        fputs($fp,' ',999);                    
     } 

 fclose($fp);
```