# File Handling using PHP

Tags: php, text-files

Can anyone tell the method to modify/delete the contents of a text file using PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearing content of text file using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073609/clearing-content-of-text-file-using-php)

Comment: *(tutorial)* [Practical PHP - Chapter 8: Files](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/8/0/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

```
if (is_writable($filename)) {
  if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w')) {
     echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
     exit;
  }
  if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
    exit;
  }

  echo "Success, wrote to file ($filename)";

  fclose($handle);
}
```

Write "" to a file to delete its contents.

To delete contents line by line use:

```
$arr = file($fileName);

unset($arr[3]); // 3 is an arbitrary line
```

then write the file contents. Or are you referring to memory mapped files?

Comment: You can use stream seeking http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/streamwrapper.stream-seek.php and writing http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/streamwrapper.stream-write.php if your use fopen.

Comment: This tutorial may offer you what you are after (for binary files - so lower level file editing) http://en.kioskea.net/faq/998-parsing-a-binary-file-in-php

Answer (score 3):

Using `file_put_contents`:

```
file_put_contents($filename, 'file_content');
```

If you want to append to the file instead of replacing it's contents use:

```
file_put_contents($filename, 'append_this', FILE_APPEND);
```

(`file_out_contents` is the simpler alternative to using the whole `fopen` complex.)

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways to read files. Large files can be handled very fast using

```
$fd = fopen ("log.txt", "r"); // you can use w/a switches to write append text
while (!feof ($fd)) 
{ 
   $buffer = fgets($fd, 4096); 
   $lines[] = $buffer; 
} 
fclose ($fd);
```

you can also use file_get_contents() to read files. its short way of achieving same thing.

to modify or append file you can use

```
$filePointer = fopen("log.txt", "a");
fputs($filePointer, "Text HERE TO WRITE");
fclose($filePointer);
```

YOU CAN ALSO LOAD THE FILE INTO ARRAY AND THEN PERFORM SEARCH OPERATION TO DELETE THE SPECIFIC ELEMENTS OF THE ARRAY.

`$lines = file('FILE WITH COMPLETE PATH.')`; // SINGLE SLASH SHOULD BE DOUBLE SLASH IN THE PATH SOMTHING LIKE C://PATH//TO//FILE.TXT
Above code will load the file in $lines array.